# How to handle ESP pages in Appweb web server

Tags: model-view-controller, webserver

Is anyone knows how ESP pages are getting loaded in Appweb server. 
or can anyone what exactly the uses of esp.json which is newly introduced in appweb 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

ESP pages are compiled, either dynamically or they can be pre-compiled into a shared library / DLL.

The esp.json file controls ESP including the compilation and runtime.

There is lots of doc at: https://embedthis.com/esp/doc/ and the esp.json file is documented there.